# How can I get geo data (longitude / latitude) for addresses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'd like to create a Heat Map. I've done this before but the data was all US counties. There are roughly 3200 US counties. We got the data from the Census Bureau's website, dumped the data in our database, used MapBox, C# code and displayed the heat map.

Now, we want to display a Heat Map but it's street addresses/state/zip data that we have.

The previous developer used Google API. The user enters their address and clicks submit. Looks like the code calls Google API and it displays the map with that address. This involves too much work for the user.

I don't think we can get all the Geo data for all the addresses we have. We have about 1 million rows of data. Not everything needs to be displayed on the map. It's whatever a client has which could be maybe 100 places to show on a map.

I'm thinking we can display a map (maybe using Map Box), automatically call Google API and then display the map locations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/

Comment: If you're already using the Google Maps API, it handles the map, markers, address-to-gps decoding (geocoding), and most anything else you need.  Their documentation is excellent and I would recommend checking it out.